# Iterate array of SKShapeNodes

Tags: arrays, swift

Struggling with how to iterate through an array of SKShapeNodes. I seem to be able to go through it in DidMoveToView(), but, not WhenTouchesBegan().

From GameScene.swift:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
...
     var areaTwo = SKShapeNode()
     var areaThree = SKShapeNode()
     var areaFour = SKShapeNode()
     var currentArea = SKShapeNode()

//CGPaths as UIBezierPaths set here


     var areas = [SKShapeNode]()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
...
          areaTwo = SKShapeNode(path: areaTwoPath.CGPath)
          areaThree = SKShapeNode(path: areaThreePath.CGPath)
          areaFour = SKShapeNode(path: areaFourPath.CGPath)
          let areas = [areaTwo, areaThree, areaFour]
...
//this works
          for area in areas {
               area.lineWidth = 4
                addChild(area)
          }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch in touches {
          let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
              currentArea.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor()

//this does not work! No errors thrown. Just doesn't seem to do anything.             
              for area in areas{
                   currentArea = area
                   if currentArea.containsPoint(location) {
                        currentArea.fillColor = UIColor.redColor()
               }
             }
         }
    }
```

What is frustrating is if I use a series of if...else if...else if I can check every single area, but, can't check them through the array.

Comment: You have two `areas`, an instance property and a local let-constant. Where are assigning values to instance property `areas`?

Comment: OOPer is correct on this. You are shadowing areas in `didMoveToView`. Change `let areas = ...` to `areas = ...`

Comment: DOH! That would likely be the problem! <head slap>

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not quite clear about your target. if you simply want a way to iterate child nodes, you can try

```
//init child nodes
for i in 1...2{
  let areaNode = SKShapeNode()
  ...
  areaNode.name = "area"
  parentNode.addChild(areaNode)
}

//iteration
for node in parentNode.children{
  if node.name == "area"{
    print("here we find a child area")
  }else{
    print("some irrelevant node found")
  }
}
```

Btw, the reason why your code in `didMoveToView()` work is you declared an new `areas` array, which in fact is an in-method variable replaced the role of previous class property `areas`

Comment: Thank you for the additional pointers. Will try and implement this.